# Retrieve $_POST for two pages

Tags: php, html, session

I need to save my submit form data like:Name for two pages... 
For some reason the $_POST only saves data for the "action" page, but cannot be retrived after the action page. 
Here's my code: 
  HTML (form):

```
 <html> 
 <body> <form name="input" action="staff.php" method="post"> 
         Username: <input type="text" name="Name">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the next page after submiting and it works... (staff.php)

```
<html>
<?php 
session_start(); 
echo "You have choosen". $_POST['Name']; // it shows what you've choosen... 
 ?> 
<form name="input" action="staff2.php" method="post">
Age: <input type="text" name="Age">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>  
</html>
```

Ok and after age submiting Name and Age stop working... (staff2.php)
Here's the code:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
echo "You have choosen". 
$_POST['Name'];  //it does't show Name.. Please help! 
$_POST['Age']; // it doesnt't show this either..  
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you have a session running pass them as session variables.

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, there is nothing wrong on the first page. So don't change anything.

The second page. The post works. Then add a hidden input to preserve it and carry it on the next one:

```
<?php
echo "You have chosen: ". $_POST['Name']; // it shows what you've choosen... 
?> 
<form name="input" action="staff2.php" method="post">
Age: <input type="text" name="Age">
<input type="hidden" name="Name" value="<?php echo $_POST['Name']; ?>" /> <!-- this one -->
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

On the third and final page. Properly concatenate the variables:

```
echo 'You have chosen: <br/>'; 
echo $_POST['Name'] . '<br/>';  // this should carry the hidden input you set on the last page
echo $_POST['Age']; 
//^^ you forgot the echo
```

Comment: Ok thank you :) I've decided to use session=post instead, but can you please tell me how to retrive this information into a table from mysql ?